# Seaborn plots in a nested for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, plot, seaborn

I am attempting to loop through a list of states and months to plot score distributions for each state in the list by month.

The desired outcome would be each state's score distribution being represented on its own plot by month. So each state plot should have two lines (distribution for scores in said state by month1 and month2).

Below is a representation of my code.

the lists are created like so:

```
state_list = df['StoreStateName'].tolist()

states = set(state_list)

months = [
         '2020-11'
         ,'2020-12'
         ]
```

Then my attempt at looping through the two lists to create the plots:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (18,28))
nrow = 10
ncol = 5
i = 1
for state in states:
    temp1 = df[df['StoreStateName'] == state]
    for month in months:
        temp2 = temp1[temp1['Month'] == month] 
    plt.grid()
    plt.subplot(nrow, ncol, i)
    plt.title(state) 
    sns.distplot(a=temp2['Score'], hist=False, label=month)
    plt.legend()
    i += 1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When I do this the output looks like:

[image: Example Plots]

The first loop seems to be working but the subplots are missing the November distribution.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out my code was out of order.

Here is the code that fixed my issue:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (18,28))
nrow = 10
ncol = 5
i = 1
for state in states:
    temp = df[(df['StoreStateName'] == state)]
    plt.subplot(nrow, ncol, i)
    plt.grid()
    plt.title(state) 
    for month in months:
        temp2 = temp[(temp['Month'] == month)] 
        sns.distplot(a=temp2['Score'], hist=False, label=month)
        plt.legend().remove()
    i += 1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc=4, bbox_to_anchor=(2.0, 0.5), prop={'size': 18})
plt.show()
```